# Emphasizing "X days left in trial"

Tags: color, trial-period

My product shows an indication for number of days left in the free trial:

[image: 11 days left in trial - Contact Sales]

When the number of days left is 3 or less, I would like to emphasize it by coloring in red. What would be the correct way?

1. Coloring just the number of days:

   [image: "3" is colored]
2. Coloring "X days":

   [image: "3 days" is colored]
3. Coloring the entire sentence:

   [image: "3 days left in trial" is colored]

Comment: Consider making the number bold, to give it some weight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Second option seems most appealing to me as it's visible enough but not too much.

Have you considered showing a reverse progress bar visually displaying the countdown? Like this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would, first of all drop the contact sales button and make the text clickable linking to where to buy the full version. As according to me having a button visible throughout the trial period tends to add visual weight. As for the color I think coloring the whole text would be better.